# Removing Jira issues through Python script

Tags: python, jira

We have jirapython integration library.  We create issue through python script.like create_issue. But same as i want remove issue function. I referred many docs,blogs and official site. But i did not get this solution. Can anyone pls help me this issue.

Comment: https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html They have a delete() method there, not sure what else you need

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty trivial. If you want to delete an issue, you need the issue object. One way to obtain the object is via `jira.create_issue()` function that you mentioned in which case you can delete it as follows:

```
issue = jira.create_issue(...)
...
issue.delete()
```

Alternatively if you happen to know the ID of the issue you want to delete you could delete it like so:

```
issue = jira.issue("EXAMPLE-244")
issue.delete()
```

If you don't know the IDs of the issues you want to delete, you might first have to find the issues via the `jira.search_issues()` function. This would look like:

```
issues = jira.search_issues('project="%s" AND summary~"%s"' % ("project_key", "issue title"), maxResults=100)

for issue in issues:
    issue.delete()
```